# JBox2D applyLinearImpulse doesn't work

Tags: java, box2d, physics

So i have this line of code:

```
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W)&&canJump())
    {
        body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vec2(0, 30), cam.screenToWorld(body.getPosition()));
        System.out.println("I can jump!");
    }
```

My problem is that the console display `I can jump!` but the body doesn't do that. Can you explain to me if i do something wrong?

Some more code.
This function creates my 'hero' the one supposed to jump.

```
private Body setDynamic(float width, float height, float x, float y)
{
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(width/2, height/2);

    BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
    bd.allowSleep = true;
    bd.position = new Vec2(cam.screenToWorld(new Vec2(x + width / 2, y + height / 2)));
    bd.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
    bd.userData = new BodyInfo(width, height);

    Body body = world.createBody(bd);
    body.createFixture(shape, 10);

    return body;
}
```

And this is the main update loop:

```
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A))
    {
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vec2(-10*delta, body.getLinearVelocity().y));
    }
    else if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D))
    {
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vec2(10*delta, body.getLinearVelocity().y));
    }
    else
    {
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vec2(0, body.getLinearVelocity().y));
    }

    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W)&&canJump())
    {
        body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vec2(0, 30), body.getPosition());
        System.out.println("I can jump!");
    }
    world.step(delta * 0.001f, 10, 5);

}
```

Comment: Try to not convert the coordinates. Simply keep `body.getPosition()`. Also, make sure that the order of the params is correct (impulse, point). Also, make sure that you don't call World.clearForces() before you call World.step();

Comment: Even without the conversion it still doesn't work. I don't call world.clearForces() either. I am a little confused right now.

Comment: Then we need to see more code. Like the game loop, body creation. Make sure mass of your body is not zero and that you created the body dynamic.

Comment: Added the game loop and body creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding your update loop was useful :D

The problem is that you are overwriting the linear velocity each step.To move the player, apply forces. And do not set the speed, never.

Try something like this:

```
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A))
{
    body.applyLinearForce(new Vec2(-3000, 0), body.getPosition());
}
else if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D))
{
    body.applyLinearForce(new Vec2(3000, 0), body.getPosition());
}

if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W) && canJump())
{
    body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vec2(0, 30), body.getPosition());
    System.out.println("I can jump!");
}

world.step(delta, 10, 5);
world.clearForces();
```

Comment: Setting the velocity is fine for doing things such enforcing a max velocity.

Comment: @ClassicThunder: http://tinyurl.com/7fwfn53  :D I think it's a bad idea. Isn't the rule to only set velocity when using kinematic bodies?

Comment: It must be something i did wrong because when i change my code with yours my body will not move left / right anymore. :D I think forces and impulses don't work.

Comment: Are you sure that your delta value is correct? Delta should be 1/fps. So for 60 fps, your delta should be: 0.0167

Comment: I got this running, but the thing is i need big values for the parameters. For a body with the `density = 0.1f` i need a 3k force to move it. It may be the delta wrong.

Comment: So, is it working right now?

Comment: Nope. If i modify delta the game is running faster but still the same results.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3031/discussion-between-romeo-and-martijn-courteaux)